# Where does the spacing above the validation summary come from and how can I remove it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following problem:

[image: Problem with spacing]

The code generating this comes from a bootstrap template, it looks like this:

```
@model LoginOrRegisterViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registreer je vandaag bij de Zaaikalender";
}

<!-- Fixed main screen -->
<div id="login" class="bg imglogin">

    <!-- Signup box inspired by http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-amp-signup-forms-in-panel -->
    <div id="signupbox" style="padding: 3.5%; font-size: 12px;" class="mainbox span12">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div style="float:right; font-size: 85%; position: relative; top:-10px">
                    <a id="signinlink" href="Login">Inloggen</a>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="panel-body">

                @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-horizontal", @role="form"}))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary()  
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3" style="color: black;">
                            @Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Register.FullName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.Register.FullName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Volledige naam", @AutoComplete ="off" } )
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3" style="color: black;">
                            @Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Register.UserName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.Register.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Gebruikersnaam", @Autocomplete = "off" } )
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3" style="color: black;">
                            @Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Register.Email)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.Register.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "E-mail ", @AutoComplete ="off"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3" style="color: black;">
                            @Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Register.Password)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(vm => vm.Register.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Wachtwoord", @AutoComplete ="off"})
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- Button -->                                        
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Registreer</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                }

             </div><!-- End panel body -->
        </div><!-- End panel -->
    </div><!-- End signup box -->

</div><!-- End main login div -->
```

The `@Html.ValidationSummary()` above is the text. The spacing is in the form-group class, but other objects don't have it so I suspect it is something in the CSS of the validation summary. Does anyone know what?

Comment: Could you provide the working example somewhere?

Comment: @DaugilasKakaras I will create a JSFiddle. 2 minutes. :-)

Comment: Strangely enough, when I create a Fiddle the problem disappears...

=> http://jsfiddle.net/ecf7e3wh/

Comment: Could be that the problem appears when the errors are added dynamically. Try to inspect elements of the error msg, especially li, ul and whats inside li. If the problem is there fix it by setting margin/padding to `0 !important;`

Comment: Ah okay, it is something in the OTHER css. I just have to identify it. The problem appears here: http://jsfiddle.net/ecf7e3wh/1/

Comment: Okay found it, you were right. It is something in `li` and `ul` styling. Specifically, there was a margin in `li` and `ul`: 
`ul {
    text-align:left;
    margin: 5% 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
li {
    margin: 0 0 0 5%;
    padding: 0;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the margin from `<ul>` element of error wrapper.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ah83Ln4L/

Just add this to your style.css:

```
.validation-summary-errors ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```